# image viewer syntax issue fileChooser method

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble with my image viewer it is asking for a return method on my file chooser. the program is supposed to open a single image for a cat.

i dont know how to fix my syntax error.

I just want to get past the problem with the filechooser in the image viewer method to move on to see if i have more problems, Im new to GUI
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g ImageViewerr.java

ImageViewerr.java:32: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  private fileChooser()
          ^
1 error

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
   import java.io.File;

   public class ImageViewerr extends JFrame
 {
private JPanel imagePanel;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JLabel imageLabel;
private JButton button;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;

public ImageViewerr()
 {
setTitle( "Image Viewer" );
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

buildImagePanel();
buildButtonPanel();

add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

pack();
setLocationRelativeTo( null );
setVisible( true );

    private fileChooser()
  {

fileChooser = new JFileChooser( "." );  

    fileNameExtensionFilter defaultFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(      "Image Files", "jpg"
                                                                                           ,"gif", "png" );
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter( defaultFilter );

    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(
                    new FileNameExtensionFilter( "JPEG Files", "jpg" ) );

    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(
                    new FileNameExtensionFilter( "GIF Files", "gif" ) );

    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(
                    new FileNameExtensionFilter( "PNG Files", "png" ) );

    fileChooser.setFileFilter( defaultFilter );

    fileChooser.setDialogTitle( "Select Image File" );
    }
  }

 private void buildImagePanel()
{
  imagePanel = new JPanel();

  imageLabel = new JLabel("Click here to " +
                          "get an image");

  imagePanel.add(imageLabel);
}

private void buildButtonPanel()
 {
   buttonPanel = new JPanel();
   menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);

  button = new JButton("Get Image");

  button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


   buttonPanel.add(button);
 }

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{ 
  File selectedFile;
  ImageIcon image;
  String filename;
  int fileChooserStatus;

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{ 

  fileChooserStatus = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( ImageViewer.this );

 if( fileChooserStatus == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )
{
     selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
     filename = selectedFile.getPath();
     image = new ImageIcon( filename );

     imageLabel.setIcon( image );
     imageLabel.setText( null );

    pack();
  }


  }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
 new ImageViewerr();
}

}
```

Comment: *"it is asking for a return method on my file chooser."*  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: `filename = selectedFile.getPath();
     image = new ImageIcon( filename );`
should better be: `image = new ImageIcon( selectedFile );` - I don't know why people insist on turning files into 'strings representing the path to a file'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private fileChooser()
```

Should be:

```
private void fileChooser()
```

Without a return type, Java will presume it is a constructor.